# Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from address to address payable requested

Tags: solidity, payable, selfdestruct

```
function endSuply() public {
    require(msg.sender == admin,"only admin can end the token sale");
    require(tokenContract.transfer(admin, tokenContract.balanceOf(address(this))),"balance not transferring");

    selfdestruct(admin);
}
```

here admin is a state variable declared as `address admin;`

But the error pops up and doesn't compile !

I just need to disable the contract, how can it be done ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Elsewhere in the contract, find `address admin;` and declare it as `address payable admin;`.

Alternatively, `selfdestruct(msg.sender);` because `require(msg.sender == admin);` ensures they are the same and `msg.sender` should be `payable`.

A word of caution. `selfdestruct` is an inelegant way to stop a contract and could lead to non-trivial problems. Consider using Open Zeppelin Pausable.sol instead.

Hope it helps.

Comment: `selfdestruct(msg.sender);` also gives the same lint error.

`Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from address to address payable requested.`

Comment: That's quirky. With solidity 0.8.13 that error does indeed bubble up. Wrapping in `payable` like `selfdestruct(payable(msg.sender));` is a work-around. As an aside, have a look over here for some opinionated opinions about refraining from `selfdestruct` in most situations. https://blog.b9lab.com/selfdestruct-is-a-bug-9c312d1bb2a5